# JavaScript - Properly Extract Deep Object Properties and Construct New Object

Tags: javascript, api, ecmascript-6

Suppose the following array of objects is returned from an API:

```
const data = [
    { // first item
        meta: {
            stems: [
                "serpentine",
                "serpentinely"
            ]
        },
        hwi: {
            hw: "sep*pen*tine",
            prs: [
                {
                    mw: "ˈsər-pən-ˌtēn",
                    sound: {
                        audio: "serpen02"
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        shortdef: [
            "of or resembling a serpent (as in form or movement)",
            "subtly wily or tempting",
            "winding or turning one way and another"
        ]
    },
    { // second item
        meta: {
            stems: [
                "moribund",
                "moribundities",
                "moribundity"
            ]
        },
        hwi: {
            hw: "mor*i*bund",
        },
        fl: "adjective"
    }
]
```

I want to create a function that will generate a new array of objects. The objects in this new array will consist of data from the old objects, just rearranged. This is how I expect a new array to look, for example:

```
[
  {
    word: 'serpentine',
    definitions: [
      'of or resembling a serpent (as in form or movement)',
      'subtly wily or tempting',
      'winding or turning one way and another'
    ]
  },
  {
    word: 'moribund',
    definitions: [
      'being in the state of dying : approaching death',
      'being in a state of inactivity or obsolescence'
    ],
    partOfSpeech: 'adjective'
  }
]
```

I do this with the following function:

```
const buildNewData = arr => {
  const newData = []
  arr.forEach(item => {
    newData.push({
      ...item.meta.stems[0] && { word: item.meta.stems[0]},
      ...item.shortdef && { definitions: item.shortdef },
      ...item.fl && { partOfSpeech: item.fl },
      ...item.hwi.prs[0].mw && { pronunciation: item.hwi.prs[0].mw}
    })
  })
  return newData
}
buildNewData(data)
```

You may be curious as to why I use `...item.meta.stems[0] && { word: item.meta.stems[0]}` in the creation of the new objects. This is to check if the property exists in the original object. If it doesn't exist, the expression will evaluate to false and therefore not be added to the new object. The first object in the original array does not have the `fl` property, so it evaluates to false when the new object is being constructed.

But this doesn't work when looking up a property that is an array. The code above fails with the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. That's because the second item does not have a `prs` array under the `hwi` property, so the lookup fails.

Since I cannot control what data is returned from the API, how do I write a function that successfully creates a new array of objects in the format I've specified, without causing an error? I already have a solution to not add particular properties if they do not exist, but how do I take into account arrays?

More generally, I'm curious if there is a standardized way of extracting data from objects programmatically that prevents errors like this from occurring. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional guard so:

```
...item.hwi.prs[0].mw && { pronunciation: item.hwi.prs[0].mw}
```

becomes

```
...(Array.isArray(item.hwi.prs) && item.hwi.prs[0].mw) && { pronunciation: item.hwi.prs[0].mw}
```

which can be shortened to:

```
...(item.hwi.prs && item.hwi.prs[0].mw) && { pronunciation: item.hwi.prs[0].mw}
```

if you are confident that if *item.hwi.prs* exists its value will be an array that has a *0* value that can be spread.

```js
const data = [
    { // first item
        meta: {
            stems: [
                "serpentine",
                "serpentinely"
            ]
        },
        hwi: {
            hw: "sep*pen*tine",
            prs: [
                {
                    mw: "ˈsər-pən-ˌtēn",
                    sound: {
                        audio: "serpen02"
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        shortdef: [
            "of or resembling a serpent (as in form or movement)",
            "subtly wily or tempting",
            "winding or turning one way and another"
        ]
    },
    { // second item
        meta: {
            stems: [
                "moribund",
                "moribundities",
                "moribundity"
            ]
        },
        hwi: {
            hw: "mor*i*bund",
        },
        fl: "adjective"
    }
];

const buildNewData = arr => {
  const newData = []
  arr.forEach(item => {
    newData.push({
      ...item.meta.stems[0] && { word: item.meta.stems[0]},
      ...item.shortdef && { definitions: item.shortdef },
      ...item.fl && { partOfSpeech: item.fl },
      ...(Array.isArray(item.hwi.prs) && item.hwi.prs[0].mw) && { pronunciation: item.hwi.prs[0].mw}
    })
  })
  return newData
}

let newData = buildNewData(data);
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need to check existence of properties in an Object:

Use Optionnal chaining: https://javascript.info/optional-chaining

It returns a type undefined if the prop doesn't exist (but not string "undefined" ;) )

For desired order in new array, add numbers before the names of props.

```
  let newData = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

   newData[i] = {};

   if (data[i]?.meta?.stems[i] != undefined)
    newData[i].word = data[i].meta.stems[i];

   if (data[i]?.shortdef != undefined) {
    newData[i].definitions = data[i].shortdef.join(', ') + '.';
    newData[i].definitions = newData[i].definitions.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newData[i].definitions.substring(1); // Capitalize first letter
   }

   if (data[i]?.fl != undefined)
    newData[i].partOfSpeech = data[i].fl;
  }

  console.log(...newData);
```